# Tag navigation in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope, exuberant-ctags

With cscope integrated Vim, I can navigate back using the ctrl-T and see the current tag stack position using :tags . But how do I go forward in the stack? The only thing I could find from the man pages is to go to the function definition (like ctrl-])

Comment: @Kent I am not using ctags as-suck. I am using ctags. So :ta is not wirking

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tag stack is created by all your "jump to definition". Each time you do `<C-]>`, the tag you jump to is added to the tag stack and you are able to use `<C-t>` or `:pop` to jump back to the previous tag in the tag stack or `:tag` to go the other way. Both `:tag` and `:pop` take an optional count so `:5pop` would go to the fifth previous tag.

See `:help tagstack`.

Answer (score 27):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to move forwards and backwards respectively through the jump list. This works with tag commands since they count as jump movements.

So to:

- Jump to a tag: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.
- Jump back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
- Jump to a tag again: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: That works in the jump list (and tag list as a side effect). But they are not exactly tag navigation.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding this answer because I don't have the rep to edit or comment on the accepted answer, but `<C-t>` actually corresponds to the `:pop` command, not the `:tag` command as was stated.

`:pop` is for moving "backwards" in the tag stack (will result in 'at bottom of tag stack' message) and is the command with the default keybinding `<C-t>`

`:tag` is for moving "forwards" in the tag stack (will result in 'at top of tag stack' message).

I am not aware of any keybinding for :tag like  for moving backwards, so I have mapped  (not ) to tag.

`nnoremap <C-[> :tag<CR>`

Comment: I've edited the accepted answer. Surprised it was left so long!